# Sinatra "after" filter

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Sinatra has a "before" filter, but is there an easy way to implement an "after" filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be some [patch](http://github.com/jschementi/sinatra/commit/e87b0babd3d31c2d7c23bc270ffa42f6461c8982) for that.

Comment: Ah yes, looks great! I hope they implement this into the real gem. Thank you